# multiple conditions in SPARQL ASK query

Tags: regex, sparql, multiple-conditions

I need to include few conditions in SPARQL ASK query.

I tried --

- nesting a few `ASK` queries
- nesting `SELECT` statement inside `ASK` query
- just putting all the conditions in `ASK` query

-- but the answer is always wrong.

I've checked all the conditions one by one and it's working, so the problem is just in query construction.

Approximately this is what I want:

```
PREFIX m: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>
ASK
  {
    ?kraj  m:country        "United Kingdom".
    ?rez   m:director_name  ?rezyser .
    FILTER regex(?rezyser, "James", "i")
  }
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

If you simply put multiple clauses in the `WHERE` clause of any SPARQL query then you are asking that **ALL** those clauses must be satisfied in order for an answer to be returned.

It sounds like what you actually want to know is if **ANY** of those clauses are satisfied in which case you need to use the `UNION` operator e.g.

```
PREFIX m: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>
ASK
{
  {
    ?kraj m:country "United Kingdom".
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?rez m:director_name ?rezyser.
    FILTER regex(?rezyser, "James", "i")
  }
}
```

You can have as many branches in your `UNION` as you need, for example if you wanted to check if any of 4 clauses were satisfied:

```
ASK
{
  {
    # Clause 1
  }
  UNION
  {
    # Clause 2
  }
  UNION
  {
    # Clause 3
  }
  UNION
  {
    # Clause 4
  }
}
```